# Navigation Drawer Android get custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, navigation-drawer

I have a customview to use on my Drawer Navigation:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.extasis.musichunter.NavigationDrawerFragment" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/buscador"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista_log"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccc"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

I have this on my Navigation Drawer class, and works great:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Creamos el LinearLayout
        mDrawerView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

        return mDrawerView;


    }
```

I can compile and try my app, but I want to extract the childs of the view (in this case the list view to a variable)

```
View to extract:  android:id="@+id/lista_log"
```

Tried:

```
mDrawerListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lista_log);
mDrawerListView = (ListView) container.findViewById(R.id.lista_log);
mDrawerListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lista_log);
```

Sorry my english, I will hope that you can understand me. Thanks

MainActivity.java
http://pastebin.com/F7jpaNZr

NavigationDrawerFragment.java
http://pastebin.com/cEtD24zv

Comment: Why you set navigationDrawer in Fragment? As far as I know it should be in Activity. Have you tested Android sample: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Sure, Im using eclipse + ADT when you select the Navigation Type: "Navigation Drawer", the default template are these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can make this works on this way:

<del>mDrawerListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lista_log);

    mDrawerListView = (ListView) container.findViewById(R.id.lista_log);

    mDrawerListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lista_log);</del>

```
mDrawerListView = (ListView) mDrawerView.findViewById(R.id.lista_log);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following xml is showing how navigationDrawer can be set for an Activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

onCreate() method in Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  
                mDrawerLayout,         
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  
                R.string.drawer_open,  
                R.string.drawer_close  
                ) 
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I modify the ListView with the LinearLayout of my question, And I want get the listview and the editText separately. :)

Comment: Can you show how your main Activity look like? I have edited my answer where I initialize mDrawerList.